# Solve and plot an equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have this equation I would like to solve and plot the y[x] but is not working?!

```
a = 1.3; k = -0.002; b = 0.2; f = 0.69; y0 = 67.8; 
Solve[{
  a*y[x]^2 - b*y[x]*(3*y[x]^2 + (3*k)/x^2 - f) + (k*(a - 2/3))/x^2 - a*(f/3) == 0,
  y[1] == y0},
  y, x
]
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `Solve[..., {y, x}]`? Or did you mean to use `DSolve`?

Comment: It doesn't give me anything!!

Comment: Is this a differential equation? Please take a look at a few examples on the `DSolve` help page before rephrasing/editing your question.

Comment: Or maybe you could try `Reduce[yourEquations, y[x]]`? Can you show us the original form of this equation?

Comment: Your equations are inconsistent.  First of all, you should be solving for `y[x]`. When you do that and plug in $x=1$, you get something that's not equal to `y0`. As other comments are mentioning, the syntax you're using, along with the condition `y[1] == y0`, suggests that you are trying to solve a differential equation, but the equation you've written is not a differential equation.  Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 1.3; k = -0.002; b = 0.2; f = 0.69; y0 = 67.8;
expr = a*y[x]^2 - 
    b*y[x]*(3*y[x]^2 + (3*k)/x^2 - f) + (k*(a - 2/3))/x^2 - 
    a*(f/3) /. y[x] -> y // Rationalize
Reduce[{expr == 0, y == y0 // Rationalize}, x] // ToRules
expr /. {%}
```

It means that only when $x=\pm\sqrt{6007/13576087635}\approx \pm 0.000665184$, $y=y0=67.8$

```
plot = ContourPlot[{expr == 0, y == y0}, {x, 0, .03}, {y, -80, 80}, 
  PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no required solution. First,

```
a = 1.3; k = -0.002; b = 0.2; f = 0.69; y0 = 67.8; sol = 
Solve[Rationalize[a*y[x]^2 - b*y[x]*(3 y[x]^2+(3 k)/x^2 - f) + (k*(a - 2/3))/x^2 - a*(f/3),0]==0,y[x]];
```

produces three solutions which are long so I omit these.
Second, the plots

```
Plot[y[x] /. sol[[1]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[y[x] /. sol[[2]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[y[x] /. sol[[3]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

clearly show no one of these satisfies `y[1] ==  67.8`.

Comment: I'm working on this condition, you right

Comment: What about this equation, I changed the equation little a bit I got no answer
a = 1.3; k = -0.002; b = 0.2; f = 0.69; y0 = 67.8; sol = 
Solve[Rationalize[a*y[x]^2 - b*y[x]*Sqrt[3 y[x]^2+(3 k)/x^2 - f]+ (k*(a - 2/3))/x^2 - a*(f/3),0]==0,y[x]];

Comment: @M.SMD: `sol = Solve[
  Rationalize[
    a*y[x]^2 - 
     b*y[x]*Sqrt[3*y[x]^2 + (3* k)/x^2 - f] + (k*(a - 2/3))/x^2 - 
     a*(f/3), 0] == 0, y[x]]` produces three solutions and a warning.